# C# Windows Forms Interacting With Web Browser

Tags: c#, selenium, web, browser

I have developed a Windows Form application in C# that interacts with a phone system.

I would like to add click to dial functionality to the application.

When I click on a telephone number in a web browser I would like to copy the telephone number into a string and execute some code in my Windows Form application.

I have looked into using Selenium but it seems that the user must be using an instance of Chrome that Selenium has created to complete the above task.

Comment: Are you talking about standalone browser or browser control embedded in your application?

Comment: A standalone browser. Thanks

Comment: Are we can assume that all telephone numbers are embedded into anchor tag with `tel:` scheme href? Check [The tel URI for Telephone Numbers proposal](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3966) for more information.

Comment: I have written automation to do this same thing. Yes it will need to use the chrome browser initiated by webdriver. You should be able to easily pull the value out of the application and do what you want. The problem you are going to run into is that when you initiate the call, that will bring up a windows auth box in the browser to authorize audio. That will require you to use AutoIT in order to interact with windows objects.

Comment: I do this all the time. Use Selenium for your interactions with the browser and then use Coded UI (since you identify as a C# user) to interact with windows forms. They both execute fine from the same test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I used the tel: protocol used in HTML href.

I then set my program to be the default handler of tel:.